# How to fix 'Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.'

Tags: c#

I get the following problem in the code below
Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.

> Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized

```
public void Refreshdata()
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from ProgressReport", con);
   SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   _ = sda.Fill(ds);
   GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
   GridView1.DataBind();
}
Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[InvalidOperationException: Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.]
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.GetConnection3(DbDataAdapter adapter, IDbCommand command, String method) +1774041
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +114
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +180
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet) +126
   WebApplication5.WebForm1.Refreshdata() +229
   WebApplication5.WebForm1.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +124
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +108
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +90
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1533
```

Comment: What is your `con`? Do you initialize it?

Comment: public SqlConnection con { get; private set; }

Comment: Okay, I edited your question a bit, but it still confuses me. What tells us that the problem is in this snippet of code? You are working with a database. Which one? Have you checked your DB connection?

Comment: I will eloborate below

Comment: I added more info to my question/post

Comment: Okay, notice that the problem is not in `Refreshdata()` method but `System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.GetConnection3()` which is on top of the stack trace. `Refreshdata()` is just the place from where we got there through `System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill()` method.

Comment: Now I want you to show me how you initialized your `con` property and I would also need your database information. Is it SQL Server, MySQL or something else. Do you have an SQL Management of sort with which we can access that database? Or is it a default local storage and not the proper db (I think it is file with a .mdb extension in your solution).

Comment: thats the thing idk how to set the con property.  I think the solution is con.open so it can fill it then I can close it, but idk

Comment: Okay, just work with me. Do you have a database?

Comment: yes its through access, but all of that is fine I really just need to know the fix

Comment: Your fix is probably in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that you need. Instead of `SqlConnection` being a property that you never set, have an ***using block*** inside your `Refreshdata` method, initial the connection with each call and dispose it at the end of using block.

```
public void Refreshdata()
{
   //or some different connection string you might need   
   string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"; 
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   {
      con.Open();

      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from ProgressReport", con);
      SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      _ = sda.Fill(ds);
      GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
      GridView1.DataBind();
   }
}
```

Maybe `SqlCommand` should also be made with using block, so it also would be disposed at the end of it. See if it implements the `Disposable` interface.

Okay this is just a starting point. Now we have to create a proper connection string. For that one, you need to extend your question with the type of database you use. If you haven't done anything with a database until this point in your project, then you have to do some research first. :))

You casually mentioned Access DB, but it is actually the crucial piece of information we've been missing here. Here you go, the material you need: https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

I'll try with this connection string first, but go through all of them, depending on your DB settings, as you haven't disclosed them yet.

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
```

For some additional reading see this https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: where do I put the string connectionstring

Comment: How do I actually get the connection string because this is what I have   string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Ml\Downloads\OneDrive_2022-11-14 (1)\Database App;Persist Security Info=False;";

Comment: "...this is what I have..." you have what, and where? And what do you mean by 'have'?

Comment: And please for the third time, can you give me your database information in clear answers? So, what database are you using? You said: "its through access", but then you put OneDrive in your connection string. Can you make some screen shots of the database you made?

Comment: idk at this point it isnt even my file I am just trying to cover for someone else.

Comment: I put "onedrive" in because I am trying to get to my database file and have a path for it.  Thats what I am asking how do I make a path from the file?  This is frustrating lol

Comment: come here and let's have a chat https://gitter.im/RedCrusaderJr-chat-room/community

Comment: Provide me with details on 1. What are you trying to do in general, like what is your problem/assignment/project in general? 2. What have you already done? 3. Do you know what a database is? 4. Do you know what type of database you plan/have to use? 5. Have you set anything about database in your project? Provide me with detailed answers on ALL the questions in plain, readable and understandable English. Provide me with snippets of code and screenshots. Provide screenshot especially for anything concerning database setup.

Comment: I really want to help you, but if you continue to communicate improperly, I'll have to give up this thread, as it seems more and more like a waste of time.

Comment: Use the Gitter chat for photos (link in a comment above) or update a question with the photos and the information I requested from you.